# Using JLabel setIcon to add image on runtime

Tags: java, jpanel, jlabel

I'm using JFileChooser to load images and display them on a JPanel at run time. Is using `setIcon()` for JLabel a good approach for this, or is there a more adequate approach?

Comment: Is there something not working? If yes, post some code. If it is working and you want some improvement ideas, post your code on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: another approach is using the Drawing class to paint the image on the panel.  I can't say as to which approach would be better though

Comment: @peeskillet, no it's working fine, I just want to know if this approach is adequate enough, I just wonder if there is a better known approach.Thank you

Comment: Setting the image as an Icon in a JLabel does not offer much flexibility (e.g. you can't paint the image with a different size or so), but ... if the JLabel is sufficient for what you want to do, then using `setIcon` is feasible as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that a JLabel and setIcon, using an ImageIcon is the easiest way to ensure that the image is actually loaded and properly displayed in your UI.

If you simply store the file-path from the selector and draw the image with a g.drawImage(...) in a paint(Graphics g)-method somewhere, you don't *know* that the image actually is loaded into memory yet. Of course, this can be remedied by using a MediaTracker, but the above JLabel/ImageIcon-approach does that for you.

Comment: `ImageIcon` is notorious for failing silently, meaning that if the image can't be read for some reason, it won't always report the fact.  `ImageIcon` is also restrict to a small sub set of image types.  Generally `ImageIO` is better for read(/writing) images as it throws an `IOException` when it fails and has a much more flexible range of image formats it can deal with and provides a pluggable API for adding more if required

Comment: True. I personally ensure that the actual file/resource itself is available and valid before going there, but indeed it will fail silently (sometimes) depending on wheat you feed it.